# pandoc not in the software center?

Tags: 16.04, software-center

Brand new to Ubuntu (16.04) here after spending a few years on Linux Mint.

There, Synaptic Package Manager is my go-to for getting stable package versions through GUI (i.e., a user-friendly interface to `apt-get`, essentially).

I assumed the analog here would be the Ubuntu Software application... but ostensibly not since `pandoc` returns no results, which is obviously false since I just installed it with `apt-get install pandoc`.

So:

1. Am I wrong that Ubuntu Software is the parallel to Synaptic?
2. If so, what *is* the proper analog?
3. If not, what might be wrong with my Ubuntu Software -- some settings awry?